# Plot data by Qt Charts ( qml - QT Creator)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml, pyside6

I want to plot data in PySide/qml application (using QT Creator). I found a nice Qt Charts module [url link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-index.html)

but in components in Qt Creator can not be found. So I installed it manually like that:

```
pip install PyQt6-Charts PyQt6
```

then I tried to `import QtCharts` in my `main.qml` file, but there is still an error: *QML module not found*

What I am doing wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you install Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should **install Qt Framework** from [here](https://www.qt.io/download),

then you see this :

[image]

**In Qt6 be sure that you installed Qt 5 Compatibility Module**

[image]

**then it will work.**

Comment: Thanks, it works, I can see the charts now! Unfortunately when I drag and drop any of the charts (pie, line,..) the error pops up: file: home/qt/work/build/qt-creator/src/plugins/qmldesigner/designercore/model/modelnode.cpp, function: hasParentProperty, line: 455

Comment: @WITC, your welcome ,Since this is another question, please ask it in a separate thread